# Как найти слово в списке и вывести это слово из списка?

Tags: python

Драсте! Есть огромный лист городов и фраза `Погода в Москва`. Как найти слово `Москва` в этом огромном списке город и вывести слово или хотя-бы индекс из списка?

Comment: `list.index(element)` вот поиск индекса элемента в листе.

Answer (score 2):

Что-то мне подсказывает, что у Вас структура списка немного сложнее, чем здесь описано. Тем не менее, если все так просто, то вот 2 способа.

1. Без цикла:

   ```
        my_list = ['Липецк', 'Волгоград', 'Погода в Москва', 'Архангельск']

        word = 'Погода в Москва'

        if word in my_list:
            print(my_list.index(word))
   ```
2. С переменной цикла:

   ```
    my_list = ['Липецк', 'Волгоград', 'Погода в Москва', 'Архангельск']

    for word in my_list:
        if word == 'Погода в Москва':
            print(my_list.index(word))
   ```